# How to disable the print screen option for the PDF viewer

Tags: javascript, jquery

We were given a task of disabling the print screen option for a PDF viewer. I have tried using code but wasn't able to give a blank page either. Please can someone help me in this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 44) {
      $("body").hide();
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Client side JS has absolutely no way to change the printing methods available to the client browser. Whoever gave you this task is wasting your time as what you're attempting to do is not possible

Comment: it is possible in other lang as jquery?

Comment: Not any client-side browser based language. no. You've also got to ask yourself - what is the point? What access are you trying to prevent and why? There are OS-level applications which can take print screens, such as the snipping tool, or the user can just download the PDF directly and gather the data from a third-party app. What you're attempting to do is pointless. As the old saying goes, if you don't want something to be public, don't put it online.

Comment: i already disabled the right click and dowload button, soo the user cannot directly download or print the pdf... But I agree for sure he can even capture pic using the phone.. But if i disable the printscreen user may not get the clear pdf right?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you actually looking for. But this code will help you to disable the print screen. You can't copy any text from the print screen. I must say this is a very weird task for the beginner. Please check what is `clipboard data` if you don't know.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
         if (keyCode == 44) {
                    stopPrintScreen();
         }
       });
    function stopPrintScreen() {
                var inpFld = document.createElement("input");
                inpFld.setAttribute("value", ".");
                inpFld.setAttribute("width", "0");
                inpFld.style.height = "0px";
                inpFld.style.width = "0px";
                inpFld.style.border = "0px";
                document.body.appendChild(inpFld);
                inpFld.select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                inpFld.remove(inpFld);
     }
     function AccessClipboardData() {
            try {
                 window.clipboardData.setData('text', "Access   Restricted");
                } catch (err) {
               console.log(error)
             }
      }
     setInterval("AccessClipboardData()", 300);
```

Comment: when i added the above code it shows an error occured on the page even before i pressed printscreen.

Comment: can you please share your code in codepen, codesandbox, or any other tools.

Comment: i did it in stackblitz, i will give the link for that , is it okay?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-euqup6?file=index.html

Comment: Even if this worked, it's so absolutely trivial to work around that it's not even worth the time taken to copy and paste this code in to your site.

Comment: i disabled the copy paste thing and also disabled right click... so im asking is it possible to disable right click as well as a part of my task